# how to find clickhouse table storage_policy using zkCli in zookeeper?

Tags: clickhouse

I am trying to build a create table SQL statement just by reading the information in zookeeper, using in zkCli.
In zookeeper at `/clickhouse/{database_pod}/tables/{shard}/{database}/{table}`, I can find the `/columns` and `/metadata` nodes for each replicated merge tree tables. But I don't know if or where I can find the `storage_policy` for the table. Do you know if I can find it in Zookeeper ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

storage_policy is not stored in the zookeeper, because it's a local property of the table.
storage_policy can be different at replicas (each node or/and each replica can have own storage_policy for the "same" table.